# Show user files in a navigator to drag and drop

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to find the way of creating an application where I can connect with the users file system and show his own directories in a div, allowing to select files and drop into an HTML5 area.

The main problem is how to get the directory tree, all related to drag and drop HTML5 is solved. The way that I imagine this application, is a div on the left where you can see the tree, and a droppable area on the right, so that user can navigate through his disk and upload files.

Any recommendation, or contribution, or whatever is wellcome. I think that this could be done! It will be hard, but I hope I could solve this!

Answer (score 0):

you DON'T GET access to any directory tree. Security measures

Comment: But using java or something? I did not especify that it has to be done with javascript. It does not mathers if the user has to accept some kind of permission request.

Comment: Sorry, then. in that case, there maybe some activex or java applet that, with the user permission, may do it. But i don't think it's advisable, that's just my opinion.

Comment: You are right. But we have the idea to improve in new technologies, we believe that it MUST be possible mixing JS file APIS, Java, Canvas or something. Thank you, I will try with active X. The problem with an applet is that it is too boring and basic, or... I do not how to say it, it is not "agile" enough, but is the better solution I think. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: exactly. I would go for activeX as nowadays, more and more people don't have the java VM installed running on their browsers or even installed on their computer

Comment: is it possible to use flash? An activex control might not work good on Linux (por ejemplo) or Mac. Maybe a flash to read the filesystem and using javascript to style or something

Comment: you make a good point. i haven't the slightiest idea even of what you would have to safeguard for you to be able to read the different filesystems. Why don't you try to make something like GMail's drag and drop? that way you would leave all the local filesystem up to the user's OS and still get a good effect